# How do I limit the global memory resources of Oracle 10g database

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

The server I am running oracle on is suffering from out of memory errors. Anyone know if/how I can limit the global memory resources that oracle will use?

I have SGA_TARGET_MAX = 500M and a session/process limit of 150, but our max concurrent sessions have not reached above 50.

Comment: hi none of the answers here elaborate on how to actually do the limiting.  Where do you put SGA_TARGET_MAX or whatever else?  I've got 3 instances of oracle running on a build server which are gobbling up memory despite not really being used.  Is this a instance start time thing or something that can be changed on the fly?  Maybe post an answer?

Answer (score 4):

You don't say how much memory your machine actually has (and whether all of it is available to the Oracle instance).
There are two types of memory used by Oracle. The first is the shared memory (SGA), the second is process memory (PGA). SGA is generally easier to control.

From SQL*Plus, try SHOW SGA. See if that matches your target.
Also try SHOW PARAMETER PGA
Then query v$process and compare the total PGA of the processes with the target.
You may have set the PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET/SGA_MAX_SIZE total too high.
Or maybe Oracle can't keep the PGA memory down to the target (eg due to sessions storing lots of information in PL/SQL arrays).

Comment: this is useful in showing that the target values are way too high but could you elaborate on how to change them?

Answer (score 0):

try using profiles and setting the SESSIONS_PER_USER limit